# Ping O' Death and iptables

Tags: iptables, ping, attacks

Is there a simple rule that can be written to stop a ping o' death with iptables?

Comment: is anything still vulnerable to the ping of death??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most modern operating systems are immune to the "ping-of-death" attack.  From the IPCHAINS HOWTO (http://www.linux.org/docs/ldp/howto/IPCHAINS-HOWTO-5.html):

> 5.3 Filtering out Ping of Death
>
> Linux boxes are now immune to the
>   famous Ping of Death, which involves
>   sending an illegally-large ICMP packet
>   which overflows buffers in the TCP
>   stack on the receiver and causes
>   havoc.
>
> If you are protecting boxes which
>   might be vulnerable, you could simply
>   block ICMP fragments. Normal ICMP
>   packets aren't large enough to require
>   fragmentation, so you won't break
>   anything except big pings. I have
>   heard (unconfirmed) reports that some
>   systems required only the last
>   fragment of an oversize ICMP packet to
>   corrupt them, so blocking only the
>   first fragment is not recommended.

You could drop icmp fragments with something like this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -f -j DROP
```

But again, unless you're trying to protect some really old equipment, this is all probably unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  The one rule that I was wondering about was the following:

iptables --append protect -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT

Comment: Because of the way iptables handles fragments it is probably a reasonable idea to block them outright anyway.  Brief description at: http://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html#ss7.3

Comment: @john: the rule you've quoted is simply an ICMP rate limiter.  It will only accept at most 1 ICMP packet/second (well, assuming that the packets are rejected by a subsequent rule).  It doesn't directly address the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It is hard to sort through various things one finds online to verify that they do what one intends them to do.

Comment: @packs: Thanks for the link, I will be sure to read through it.